# Managing Docker build steps files and using local volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I have a Dockerfile with the following build steps:

```
FROM composer:latest AS composer

COPY ./src/composer.json ./src/composer.lock ./

RUN composer install --prefer-dist

FROM node:latest AS node

COPY ./src ./
RUN yarn install

RUN yarn encore prod

FROM <company image>/php74 as base

COPY --from=composer --chown=www-data:www-data /app/vendor /var/www/vendor
COPY --from=node --chown=www-data:www-data ./public/build /var/www/public/build

# does the rest of the build...
```

and in my docker-compose file, I've got a volume for local changes

```
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www
```

The container runs fine on the CI/CD pipeline and deploys just fine, it grabs everything it needs and COPY's the correct files in the src directory. The problem is when we use a local volume for the code (for working in development). We have to composer/yarn install on the host because the src folder does not container node_modules/ or vendor/.

Is there a way to publish the node_modules/vendor directory back to the volume?

My attempts have been within the Dockerfile and publishing node_modules and vendor as volumes and that didn't work. Maybe it's not possible to publish a volume inside another volume? IE: within Dockerfile: `VOLUME /vendor`

The only other way I can think of solving this would be to write a bash script that docker run composer on docker-compose up. Then that would make the build step pointless.

Hopefully I've explained what I'm trying to achieve here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete that `volumes:` block, especially in a production environment.

A typical workflow here is that your CI system produces a self-contained Docker image.  You can run it in a pre-production environment, test it, and promote that exact image to production.  You do not separately need to copy the code around to run the image in various environments.

What that `volumes:` declaration says is to replace the entire `/var/www` directory – everything the Dockerfile copies into the image – with whatever happens to be in `./src` on the local system.  If you move the image between systems you could potentially be running completely different code with a different filesystem layout and different installed packages.  That's not what you really want.  Instead of trying to sync the host content from the image, it's better to take the host filesystem out of the picture entirely.

Especially if your developers already need Composer and Node installed on their host system already, they can just use that set of host tools for day-to-day development, setting environment variables to point at data stores in containers as required.  If it's important to do live development inside a container, you can put the `volumes:` block (only) in a [`docker-compose.override.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) that isn't deployed to the production systems; but you still need to be aware that you're "inside a container" but not really actually running the system in the form it would be in production.

You definitely do not want a Dockerfile `VOLUME` for your libraries or code.  This has few obvious effects; its most notable are to cause `RUN` commands to be able to change that directory, and (if you're running in Compose) for changes in the underlying image to be ignored.  Its actual effect is to cause Docker to create an anonymous volume for that directory if nothing else is already mounted there, which then generally behaves like a named volume.  Declaring a `VOLUME` or not isn't necessary to mount content into the container and doesn't affect the semantics if you do so.